# Unbind() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, bind

On [my page](http://goo.gl/eGPXBP), hovering any of the three colored rectangle triggers a jQuery code that hides the image and shows some text. On mobile devices I don't want to run this code, so I'm executing the code on resize() and running it only for desktop resolutions.

But it doesn't work, for some reason the code runs is all cases.

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    vertical_hover();
    $(window).on('resize', vertical_hover);

    function vertical_hover() {

        if ( window.innerWidth > 800 ) { 

            $( '.vertical_wap_inner' ).on({
                mouseenter: function () {
                    $(this).find( '.vertical_wap_inner_title' ).fadeOut(200);
                    $(this).find( 'img' ).css('visibility','hidden')
                    $(this).find( '.vertical_wap_inner_text' ).fadeIn(200);
                },
                mouseleave: function () {
                    $(this).find( '.vertical_wap_inner_title' ).fadeIn(200);
                    $(this).find( 'img' ).css('visibility','visible')
                    $(this).find( '.vertical_wap_inner_text' ).fadeOut(200);
                }
            });     

        }
        else { 

            $( '.vertical_wap_inner_title, .vertical_wap_inner img, .vertical_wap_inner_text' ).unbind();

        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Have you tried using `JQuery.off()` which is the mirror of `JQuery.on()` rather than `JQuery.unbind()` which was deprecated as of JQuery 1.7. `$( '.vertical_wap_inner' ).off('mouseenter mouseleave');`

Comment: @drake035 If your problem solved and my answer were useful, please mark it to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You try fire `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events in `resize` event while this events doesn't fire at one time.

You don't need to fire `resize` event, just fire `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event entirely.

See demo in **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8q4zfp5y/1/)**